# .Net Web Api (backend) how to store user custom permission list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, user-permissions

in my application, access to individual options is defined by individual permissions such as user_module_view, user_add, user_edit, user_delete, allowed_id_client... so that in the end result you can define any role as needed for the end client, depending on what he needs.

I wanted to store a list of such permissions after the user log in, so that they do not have to be accessed from the database each time they send request to the API.

My first thought was to save them in the JWT token, which is stored in the browser's cookies. But it turned out that the generated access token is 22KB, so when saving cookies, swagger returns an error:

```
CORS

Network Failure

URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

And the cookie is not saved, its limit is 4KB. When the access token is reduced, e.g. to 10kb, the error in swagger does not appear, the method returns the correct result, but the cookie is not saved anyway.

Is there any other, safe way that will prevent external interference in the permission list, that will allow keeping such a list in the cache and maintaining the rest full api? I don't want to keep the list of permissions in e.g. a dictionary in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scale you're looking at, you could look at simple sessions where a session ID is sent via cookie and you look it up in a session store at the backend (like redis/memcache).

The other option would be to store the JWT token in LocalStorage at the client end and send it as a HTTP header (typically, Bearer authorization is used for this).

The scale part is important here - because the moment you put a redis/memcache for looking up sessions, it can quickly become a bottleneck (both performance wise and money wise) as it will checking it for **every request** v/s simple conditional check after verifying signature of the JWT received from the client.

Comment: Is using REDIS to cache user data compatible with the RestFull API? You have to take into account that this data will only be kept in the temporary database for a certain period of time and you must handle the case of reloading it if it is deleted while the session is still active, unless REDIS has some dedicated mechanisms for this type of thing.

Comment: @blane Redis can be used to store data persistently, but it's usually not used for that purpose. Yes, you will have to handle the cache refresh part here, which in my opinion, isn't a big deal. If underlying data changes simply delete the redis data so it will be reloaded afresh from your primary data source in your usual code paths.